# Makefile always running target

Tags: makefile

I may miss something very obvious with this Makefile:

```
convert: devel/bar
  touch convert

init: devel/foo
  echo 'init'

devel/foo:
  mkdir -p devel
  touch devel/foo

devel/bar: init
  touch devel/bar
```

When I run it, the `devel/bar` target always gets called.  I'd expect it to call `convert`, check  the file `devel/bar`, and call that target only if that file is not found.  If I remove its dependency on `init`, everything works as I would expect.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not creating a file called `init`, so `init` is always out-of-date.  Therefore everything that depends on it is always out-of-date.

Answer (score 2):

There probably is no file named `init`? So it tries to update `devel/bar` (since it depends on `init`).

Consider using `.PHONY`

Comment: Using `.PHONY: init` would keep `init` out-of-date even if he created a file named `init`.  Sounds like the opposite of what he wants.

Comment: Oops, sorry. `.INTERMEDIATE` would probably do the trick. But nevertheless, that is the reason why it runs the targets - it tries to make a file called `init` first.