# Why does following makefile rebuilt target "build" everytime

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following code to untar all the files in a directory and move it to build directory. If I call make multiple times, it tries to execute "build" target everytime even if build directory already exists. Has anyone comes across this?

I found this question but it is not the same.
[Makefile always running target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289026/makefile-always-running-target)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Program: GNU Make 3.81

```
build: mkBuildDir untar 
    chmod 700 build

.PHONY: mkBuildDir untar 

mkBuildDir: 
    mkdir build 

untar: *.tar.gz
    for prefix in *.tar.gz; do \
        tar xvf $$prefix --directory=build; \
    done

clean: 
    rm -Rf build
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This *is* pretty much the same as the question you've linked.  You never create a file called `mkBuildDir`, so it's always out-of-date, so `build` is always out of date.

Your `mkBuildDir` target isn't doing anything useful (though I presume this is a cut-down makefile).  If instead you did

```
# it'd be better to list the TARFILES explicitly, though this will probably work
TARFILES=`ls *.tar.gz`

all: build untar

build: $(TARFILES)
    test -d build || mkdir build
    chmod 700 build
    for prefix in $(TARFILES); do \
        tar xvf $$prefix --directory=build; \
    done

clean: 
    rm -Rf build
```

that would probably accomplish what you're looking for.

Having too many phony targets in a Makefile is usually a makefile 'code smell'.  They are rarely the best/idiomatic way of doing things.

Comment: I think it is better to use `TARFILES=$(wildcard *.tar.gz)`. In the original case if there is no matching file name, then `TARFILES` would be `*.tar.gz` instead of an empty list. And what is more, one process creation is spared.

Comment: True, but that wildcard behaviour is true only for some settings in some shells.  Also, `$(wildcard ...)` is a GNU Make extension, so won't be portable (which may or may not be an issue).  Finally, every one of the action lines creates a new process, so saving one process here doesn't really gain much.

Comment: Parallel make seems to fail when doing that with 2 targets that both require the build directory. mkdir -p will fix it (although you might get unnecessary command output).